# Complex Time Series Problem

Tags: time-series, intermittent-time-series

I have a difficult time series problem that is stumping me.

I have registration data for a repeating annual event.   The date of the event changes every year as does the open period for registration.   I have data for 5 events.

Plot of the data look like this:

Conference 3 years ago:

[image]

Conference 2 years ago:

[image]

Conference 1 year ago:

[image]

I am being asked to take data from this year's conference UP TO 60 days prior to start and make a prediction on what total attendance will be.

I am able to develop a feature set that is comprised of binary day indicators, the registrations on a particular day away from start date (since as I mentioned the date changes each year, I use 'days prior to start' as a feature).

A sample of the training set (including the target variable here: registrations) is as follows:

[image]

To make the training set I drop the calendar date (reg_day) and move registrations to train_y while keeping all remaining features in a train_X file.   That data from all prior conferences are placed in the training set.

I then use a random forest to make predictions on the last 60 days of THIS year's conference.   My results are as follows:

[image]

Not bad - but not good enough.  My totals are about 20% off of actual when my target is about 10%

I have looked for other features that could help explain the spikes - but have had no luck.

I have tried various other approaches.   I have tried a SARIMAX model using 'this years' actual data from -200 to -60 days out using prior event data as additional exogenous features.   Results are bad.  Seems I don't have enough data to capture the relationships among the time series and that period - if anything - has low registrations and a positive trend.  When I difference the data, make predictions, and undo the difference results are terrible.

Any guidance on approach or refinements here appreciated.   I am at a loss.

Comment: If the goal is to make a prediction on what *total attendance* will be, it does not seem relevant to predict the day-to-day registration process.

Comment: What would be a preferred approach?   I don’t think I have enough data to make meaningful total predictions

Comment: Additionally,  I am trying to take into consideration ‘impact’ from this year from registrations prior to 60 days out.  Not sure how I can do that without a per day prediction